# How to prevent the body grow past the left edge of the screen?

Tags: css

I use this to align the body:

```
html{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This centers the body element quite nicely and keeps it as small as not to have to wrap any contents inside. If the contents begin to grow too much, they are wrapped but generally the body fits into the viewport. However, if the content is too big, the body becomes larger than the visible area, which would normally not be an issue, but the centering is still in effect and the body begins to grow past the left edge of the screen. I can't scroll there, only to the right.

How do I make it so that the most of this behaviour is preserved, but the body won't grow past the left edge? It's fine to scroll to the right if there is no other way, but right now this makes part of the content completely hidden. I prefer solutions that don't set `margin` and `padding` on body, as I have fixed values there.

Comment: Please supply a simplified example, with the given code, the overflowing of the content off screen should not occur, unless you mean you have too many flex items, need to see what you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
html{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It's missing a few things, but already this is much better than (abusing) flex. But `body` needs `display: inline-block` to put the alignment in effect and `text-align: initial` to reset it inside.